# Hack to upload a file from Java backend to a remote server over HTTP using Rest API.

Tags: file, transfer

My file resides on some location on my machine say C://users//abc.txt and i want to write a java program to transfer this file using REST API over HTTP. I used MockHttpServelet Request to create the request, but somehow i am unable to transfer the file

Comment: No idea about REST API but i have uploaded file on server with MySql as backend.

Comment: Not sure what backed you are using, is it MongoDB ?

Comment: Milind, Standalone Java Application is running on backend. I have a function to transfer file from my directory to some server using Rest API. The server accepts Rest API resquest. I don't want to use any protocol like scp for file transfer. The server will accept request only through Rest API

Comment: But there must be some database that would store your file ? what's that /

Comment: File is stored is some directory on my machine and not on DB. For now the file location is harcoded and not stored in DB(Say C://Users/abc.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org):**

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/upload"; // Replace with your target 'REST API' url
String filePath = "C://users//abc.txt";

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
try {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    FileEntity entity = new FileEntity(new File(filePath), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()); // Check HTTP code
} finally {
    httpClient.close();
}
```

**With Authentication:**

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/upload"; // Replace with your target 'REST API' url
String filePath = "C://users//abc.txt";
String username = "username"; // Replace with your username
String password = "password"; // Replace with your password

RequestConfig requestConfig =
  RequestConfig.custom().
    setAuthenticationEnable(true).
    build();

CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
  AuthScope.ANY,
  new UsernamePasswordCredential(username, password));

CloseableHttpClient httpClient =
  HttpClients.custom().
    setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).
    setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).
    build();
try {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    FileEntity entity = new FileEntity(new File(filePath), ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    System.out.println(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()); // Check HTTP code
} finally {
    httpClient.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Greg. Any idea where session/userCredentials needs to be specified so that server can allow access to it?

Comment: Authentication usage is an another question.
Use HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).

Comment: Will it not impact the performance? I mean when file is opened for transfer, JVM  will load the file into memory. If it's a large, i believe there will be a performance issue. Any idea how it can be avoided?

Comment: You can check it yourself to make sure that the file doesn't load into memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
String location="C:\\Usersabc.img";
Path path = Paths.get(location);
String name=location.substring(location.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);
 MultipartEntity multipart= new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);                
    try {
    multipart.addPart("image", new ByteArrayBody(Files.readAllBytes(path),  ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.getMimeType(),name));                 
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
```